# adding multiple icon footer to tableviewcontroller (one section)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

hi i would like to add a multiple icon foot to the footer of a uitableviewcontroller which only has single section in its entirety.

how do we add this?

Answer (score 1):

implement [`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Let it return a view, where you added your icons.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, tableView.frame.size.width,tableView.frame.height)]; 

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameofimage.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(someSelector:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
    [view addSubView: button];
    return [view autorelease]
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, if the footer view has multiple images, how to catch the touched event?

Answer (score 0):

To add a footer in your tableview you need to implement

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section.
```

in your UITableViewDelegate.  In that method you create and return your custom footer view

Comment: hanks for reply, if the footer view has multiple images, how to catch the touched event?